# Информер из Mysql php (новичок)

Tags: php, mysqli, изображения

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

  // Create Image From Existing File
  $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('img.jpg');

  // Allocate A Color For The Text
  $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);

  // Set Path to Font File
  $font_path = 'E:\serv\OSPanel\domains\localhost\verdana.ttf';

  // Set Text to Be Printed On Image
  $text = "**$name**";
  $text2 = "**$description**";

  // Print Text On Image
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
  imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 100, 400, $white, $font_path, $text2);


  // Send Image to Browser
  imagejpeg($jpg_image,"**$name**.jpg");

  // Clear Memory
  imagedestroy($jpg_image);?>
```

1)Хочу из БД вывести имя и описание на картинку, и сохранить файл с именем товара jpg.
2)как сделать это автоматически для всех товаров по имени товара.

Comment: укажите структуру ваших таблиц

Comment: БД называеться mybd , таблица shop , => id, name , description

Answer (score 0):

Для примера возмем что у вас есть уже установленный mysql server локально.
Там же у васуже есть табица images c полями

```
Images
id   description image_name

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'you_database';
$user = 'user_login';
$password = 'user_pass';

try {
  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);
  $sql = 'SELECT id, description, image_name
          FROM  images';
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute();
  $images = $sth->fetchAll();
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($images);

  $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
```

Comment: ok добавлю поле image, вот путь к БД mybd , таблица shop , => id, name , description , image

Comment: у меня начинается подключение к бд вот так  $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","data");

if ($connection == false) 
{
 echo "Не удалось подключится";
 echo mysqli_connect_error();
 exit();
}

Comment: гляньте книгу Марк Грубер Понимание SQL, намного легче будет если все таки читать книги в случае если что непонятно. Например непонятно как получить данные с базы, найдите книгу для начинаючих по SQL. 300-500 страниц за неделю вы прочитаете, возможно не все поймете но остальные знания будут структурированими и будете в них увернными